# Laptop HP Pavilion HDX Win8 freeze if Nvidia GeForce enabled

Tags: laptop, freeze, nvidia-geforce

I installed Windows 8 on my HP Pavilion HDX laptop. This laptop has Nvidia GeForce 8800M GTS. I noticed that my laptop freeze after some minutes. If I disabled my Nvidia GeForce in the Device Manager, no more freeze but my screen is much more slow to refresh.

I already try to download and install an update of the driver directly on the Nvidia website. but during the installation process of this driver I got errors and it failed to install the update.

Previously I had Windows 7 and I never noticed any freeze like this.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Finally, I resolved my problem by choosing another driver than NVIDIA. Here is what I do: Go to Control Panel / Device Manager / Under Display adapters, right click on my Nvidia GeForce and click Update driver software / 'Brows my computer for driver software...' / 'Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer' / In the list I choosed: 'Microsoft Basic Display Adapter' / Next. So far so good: no freeze and display is smooth. Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: You can post this as an answer and accept it if you like.

Comment: This sounds like a driver issue.  I would look toward HP or Nvidia to supply a Windows 8 driver to solve this problem.

Comment: I already try to install a more recent driver from the NVIDIA website but it failed to install. Maybe I should check on the HP website...